# JQuery mobile 1.1.1 - Use $(document).bind('pageinit'), not loading scripts

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using a script in order to make an anchor element navigate a user to the bottom of my webpage when it is clicked.

The first thing I did was call code inside the $(document).ready() function so everything will execute as soon as the DOM is loaded. Then when I navigated between pages on the mobile site I noticed my script was not working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu-button").click(function(){
            $(document).scrollTop($(".mainFooter").position().top);
         });
    });
```

However I realised why this was, in jQuery Mobile, Ajax is used to load the contents of each page into the DOM as you navigate, and the DOM ready handler only executes for the first page. To execute code whenever a new page is loaded and created, you can bind to the pageinit event which is found at the described at the bottom of this page: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/events.html

I have binded to the pageinit event, but the anchor is still not navigating the user to the bottom of the page if I navigate between different pages and then click the same anchor. I'm struggling to understand why binding to pageinit has not fixed the problem.

```
 $(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
    $("#menu-button").on('click.menu', function(){
        $(document).scrollTop($(".mainFooter").position().top);
     });
    });
```

I am aware that AJAX can be turned off in jQuery mobile and this would allow my code to run with the $(document).ready() function. Doing this has allowed me to achieve the desired functionality. Ideally though I would like to get pageinit working with AJAX enabled so that the anchor will work each time the pages are loaded with AJAX.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: have you tried to show an alert inside your mobileinit function? Does it still get fired, or is the problem actually in your menu-button event binding?

Answer (score 1):

in order to `mobileinit` to work you should place that code **before** jQuery Mobile is actually loaded. So you'll need to add links to your JS source codes as follows:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="custom-scripting.js"></script> // Place mobileinit script here
<script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
```

More about that could be found here in the [docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-pre/docs/api/globalconfig.html)

Also, worth noting is that mobileinit is basically for overriding globals, not for using normal functionality of your site.

Use other events like `pagebeforeshow`, `pageshow`, `pagebeforeload` etc... for that purpose

Comment: Can you fully explain the script loading order in the answer? Is there a problem if I load all the scripts at the end of the html page, just before `</body>`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to bind an event to something that isn't in the DOM yet. Try this instead:

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
    $(document).on('click.menu', '#menu-button', function(){
        $(document).scrollTop($(".mainFooter").position().top);
    });
});
```

or

```
$(document).bind('pagebeforeshow', function() {
    $("#menu-button").on('click.menu', function(){
        $(document).scrollTop($(".mainFooter").position().top);
    });
});
```